# Replace specific words by user dictionary and others by 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

So I have a review dataset having reviews like

> Simply the best. I bought this last year. Still using. No problems
>   faced till date.Amazing battery life. Works fine in darkness or broad
>   daylight. Best gift for any book lover.

(This is from the original dataset, I have removed all punctuation and have all lower case in my processed dataset)

What I want to do is replace some words by 1(as per my dictionary) and others by 0.
My dictionary is

```
dict = {"amazing":"1","super":"1","good":"1","useful":"1","nice":"1","awesome":"1","quality":"1","resolution":"1","perfect":"1","revolutionary":"1","and":"1","good":"1","purchase":"1","product":"1","impression":"1","watch":"1","quality":"1","weight":"1","stopped":"1","i":"1","easy":"1","read":"1","best":"1","better":"1","bad":"1"}
```

I want my output like:

```
0010000000000001000000000100000
```

I have used this code:

```
df['newreviews'] = df['reviews'].map(dict).fillna("0")
```

This always returns 0 as output. I did not want this so I took 1s and 0s as strings, but despite that I'm getting the same result.
Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: you are not splitting the string anywhere for this map to work, also you should use `dict` as a variable name as it masks python's builtin `dict` type.

Comment: @AChampion how to split the string for map to work?

Comment: post a testable fragment of your `df['reviews']`

Comment: You probably want to do something like: `df.reviews.str.split().apply(lambda review: ''.join(d.get(word, '0') for word in review))` assuming you have already lowered and removed all punctuation (and renamed `dict` to `d`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First dont use `dict` as variable name, because builtins (python reserved word), then use `list comprehension` with `get` for replace not matched values to `0`.

**Notice**:

*If data are like `date.Amazing` - no space after punctuation is necessary replace by whitespace.*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'reviews':['Simply the best. I bought this last year. Still using. No problems faced till date.Amazing battery life. Works fine in darkness or broad daylight. Best gift for any book lover.']})

d = {"amazing":"1","super":"1","good":"1","useful":"1","nice":"1","awesome":"1","quality":"1","resolution":"1","perfect":"1","revolutionary":"1","and":"1","good":"1","purchase":"1","product":"1","impression":"1","watch":"1","quality":"1","weight":"1","stopped":"1","i":"1","easy":"1","read":"1","best":"1","better":"1","bad":"1"}

df['reviews']  = df['reviews'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', ' ').str.lower()
```

---

```
df['newreviews'] = [''.join(d.get(y, '0')  for y in x.split()) for x in df['reviews']]
```

Alternative:

```
df['newreviews'] =  df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(d.get(y, '0')  for y in x.split()))
```

---

```
print (df)
                                             reviews  \
0  simply the best  i bought this last year  stil...   

                        newreviews  
0  0011000000000001000000000100000
```

Comment: Note: OP claims to already have lowered and removed punctuation, so you may be doing too much :). Also you are missing on `'Amazing'` because there is no space around the punctuation - `'... date.Amazing ...'`

Comment: @AChampion - Thank you, solution should be replace punctation by whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# clean the sentence
import re
sent = re.sub(r'\.','',sent)

# convert to list
sent = sent.lower().split()

# get values from dict using comprehension
new_sent = ''.join([str(1) if x in mydict else str(0) for x in sent])
print(new_sent)

'001100000000000000000000100000'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
df.replace(repl, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

where `df` is your dataframe and `repl` is your dictionary.